# I am creating a simple program that multiplies two numbers together using inputs and conditionals. I keep getting an error on the 12th line

Tags: python

```
question = input("Would you like to multiply two numbers together?") #asking question here 

if question.upper() == "YES": #makes sure that user input is correctly taken into account
    FirstNumber = eval(input("please enter your first number?")) # turns string into a number
    SecondNumber = eval(input("please enter your second number?")) #same here
     
    result = FirstNumber * SecondNumber # calculates the product of the two variables
    
    if result <= 1000:
        print("the result was greater than a 1000!" #checks if the result is less than or equal to 1000
        
    else:
        print('The result is ', result) # this is the line that I have trouble with 
    

else:
    print(":((((((((((((((((((((")
```

This program multiplies two numbers together if the result is greater than, or equal to, 1000.

Comment: @user56700 nope, print can print integers (the real problem is the missing parenthesis on print)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
print("the result was greater than a 1000!" #checks if the result is less than or equal to 1000
```

into this

```
print("the result was greater than a 1000!") #checks if the result is less than or equal to 1000
```

missing paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

```
question = input("Would you like to multiply two numbers together?") #asking question here

if question.upper() == "YES": #makes sure that user input is correctly taken into account
    FirstNumber = eval(input("please enter your first number?")) # turns string into a number
    SecondNumber = eval(input("please enter your second number?")) #same here

    result = FirstNumber * SecondNumber # calculates the product of the two variables

    # FIX: '<' is replaced by '>'
    if result >= 1000:
        # FIX: add ')'
        print("the result was greater than a 1000!") #checks if the result is less than or equal to 1000
        
    else:
        print('The result is ', result) # this is the line that I have trouble with 


else:
    print(":((((((((((((((((((((")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually line 10 that gives you the error. It would be helpful in the future to include the Error as displayed in console in your post/question. You're missing a closing parentheses at:

```
print("the result was greater than a 1000!"
```

Also your logic is off. You want it to print `print("the result was greater than a 1000!")`, but yet, you have it go to that when the result is less than or equal 10 1000.

Your code should be:

```
question = input("Would you like to multiply two numbers together? ") #asking question here 

if question.upper() == "YES": #makes sure that user input is correctly taken into account
    FirstNumber = eval(input("please enter your first number? ")) # turns string into a number
    SecondNumber = eval(input("please enter your second number? ")) #same here
     
    result = FirstNumber * SecondNumber # calculates the product of the two variables
    
    if result > 1000:
        print("the result was greater than a 1000!") #checks if the result is less than or equal to 1000
        
    else:
        print('The result is ', result) # this is the line that I have trouble with 
    

else:
    print(":((((((((((((((((((((")
```